# LTspice .ac analysis - expressions don't work or work inconsistently

Tags: ltspice

In .ac analysis I would like to use expressions to calculate and plot the result of a combination of sources.
I understand that the results of .ac analysis are complex numbers.  Is there any guidance on which expressions work with these and which do not.
I find that adding and multiplying works, but that more complex expressions do not.
For example I would like to use the max or min expression. These don't give an error, but give the wrong answer in a behavioural model.  Trying to use them in waveform arithmetic generates an error.
I also find that division works in waveform arithmetic, but not in a behavioural model.

I have not been able to find any information in the help, on the undocumented section of LTspice wiki or generally across the www that gives any guidance on this.

Specifically, in the simulation below

[image]

B3 gives an answer of 0 at all frequencies, but plotting the expression V(Eq2)/V(Eq1) works.
B4 gives the wrong answer.  It results in the value of V(Eq1) at all frequencies.  Trying to plot the expression max(V(Eq2),V(Eq1)) throws up an error.

[image]

Plotting the expression Im(V(Eq2)) gives the same result as plotting V(Eq2).
Plotting the expression RE(V(Eq2)) gives 0 at all frequencies.
Im and Re do not work in expressions in the behavioural models.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question should ask a question to be answered.

Answer (score 1):

An `.AC` analysis means a small-signal analysis on a circuit that is *linearized* around its operation point. What you're supplying, that `AC 1`, is a complex signal of 1 V peak, which would defeat the definition of small-signal, but which works even if it's `AC 1k` because the whole circuit is linearized.

A division is not linear (`B3`), so it can't be linearized, yet in the waveform window you can see `x/y` since that's how you plot the gain, `V(out)/V(in)`. It would not work with signals since what do you do if you have a division by zero, for example? The help will provide more info in `LTspice > Waveform Viewer > Waveform Arithmetic`, about which functions work and which not. You'll also see `re()` and `im()` (along with `mag()` and `ph()`) in there, what they do and where.

Regarding `min()` and `max()` (this latter one is not shown in the help as a function that's not available, but it's implied since `min()` is shown), you have to be a bit creative. Simply plot the ratio of the two quantities, say `x/y`, and when the plot is zero or positive it means `x>=y`, else `x<y`.

BTW, `freq`, `frequency`, and `w` are keywords that mean frequency (the first two), and pulsation (`w`), and can be plotted directly. They can even be used in equations.

Comment: Thank you for your helpful feedback.

Comment: When you say "pulsation (w)"do you mean w = 2*pi*freq ?

Comment: Is there any LTspice function that operates on complex values but returns a scalar ?

Comment: When you refer to freq and frequency it appears that these are only available in waveform arithmetic but not in behavioural models.  Is that correct ?

Comment: Yes, `w = 2*pi*f`, and there is an alternate spelling for it: `omega`. Also yes, both of these, and `f`, `freq`, and `frequency`, are only available in the waveform window. `re()`, `im()`, `mag()`, and `ph()` take complex arguments and return a real value, or did you have anything particular in mind, a specific case you wish to have, or is it a generic question?

Comment: Following your last answer I tried to add a trace with waveform arithmetic of "max(mag(V(Eq1),mag(V(Eq2))".  This generates "Error: undefined symbol in :<<max>>(mag(V(Eq1)),mag(V(Eq2)))".  When I use the .meas function I ge
tv_src: v(src)=(0dB,45°) at 10000
im_v_src: im(v(src))=(-3.0103dB,0°) at 10000
re_v_src: re(v(src))=(-3.0103dB,0°) at 10000
mag_v_src: mag(v(src))=(0dB,0°) at 10000
ph_v_src: ph(v(src))=(33.0643dB,0°) at 10000
mag2_v_src: mag(sqrt(v(src)*v(src)))=(0dB,0°) at 10000
freq_: frequency=(80dB,0°) at 10000

Comment: These results suggest to me that everything in .ac analysis is considered a complex number, even if you try to "cast" a result to a scalar by using im(), re(), mag(), ph() and that where the help says that some functions don't work with compelx numbers, it actually means they can't be used in a .ac analysis. Happy to consider alternative interpretations of what I have found.

Comment: What I am tyring to do is plot an EMC limit line eg. EN55022 Class B QP limit on an .ac analysis.  I use a frequency dependant noise source using a Laplace behavioural model, and the filter response is LTIV so works in .ac.  The only part I can't figure out is plotting the limit line which is a piece wise function of frequency.  Thanks again for the helpful discussion on this.

Comment: I never said `max()` can be used. Did you read the help section I mentioned? It looks like you haven't. Quote: `For complex data, the functions [...] are not available.`. Also, `re()`, `im()`, `mag()`, and `ph()` take complex argument and return complex with imaginary part null (I was half right). The `.AC` analysis is made with complex numbers, but the results of `.meas` are by default in dB. To change that, use `.opt meascplxfmt=cartesian` (see `LTspice > Dot Commands > .Options`). For a piecewise frequency line, use [this](http://www.ecircuitcenter.com/Circuits/ABM1/ABM1.htm#freq).